# Spock classpath resource not resolvable

Tags: java, groovy, classpath, spock

In a Spock unit test a method which pulls in a resource JSON file... inside the method which is retrieving a classpath based resource:

```
Myclass.classpath.getResource('/someJsonfile.json') //Works in WAR arhcive, but fails during a spock test and returns null
```

The above does not work, but the functionality works as desired upon deploying the WAR

The following works inside Spock for resolving a classpath resource, however breaks functionality for the WAR

```
System.getResource('/someJsonfile.json') //Works in spock test, but breaks functionality when inside WAR
```

Comment: Have you tried: `this.getClass().getResource('/someJsonfile.json')` or, if Myclass is groovy, `Myclass.getResource('/someJsonfile.json')`, or if it's java `Myclass.class.getResource('/someJsonfile.json')`

Comment: Thanks, yes the above code is run with Groovy :) ... The problem is getting to work once packaged in a WAR... I can check to see if these slight differences make a difference and report back. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in bigger projects is this:

- Create a separate module for test resources. BTW, there you can also put basic stuff like Spock extensions, base specs, Geb config, test dependencies. Important: In the test resources module you put everything under `src/main`, ***not*** `src/test`. You also import everything with `compile`, ***not*** `test` scope. Then you create a normal JAR from the module.
- Now you import the test resources module with test scope everywhere you need it. Then your resource loading problem is also solved because you can always rely on the resources being pulled from a JAR.
- You may want to go one step further, also creating a BoM (Bill of Materials) with managed test dependencies, importing that BoM everywhere you need clean version management for JUnit, Spock, Geb, Selenium etc.

So by importing the BoM you get the version management, by importing the test resources you get the actual resources, test dependencies and test base classes. The result is a reusable set of test classes and resources plus clean importing modules. And last, but not least, you can always load your resources the same way, no matter if you test inside or outside of a container.

---

**Update:**

Here are links to

- my [test dependency BoM](https://github.com/kriegaex/MavenTestBom),
- my [test resources artifact](https://github.com/kriegaex/MavenTestResources) and
- a [sample project](https://github.com/kriegaex/GebSpockSamples) using them both.

It is really simple and especially useful in corporate environments.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I don't think this is going to work in my corp env... not sure I like the idea of changing code to make tests work to be honest.

Comment: "I don't think it is going to work" is just a killer phrase, not an argument. What am I going to answer to such a statement? I can only say that the last dev team I coached (I am a Scrum coach) in a large corporate project used exactly this approach in order to avoid redundancies in a multi-module project and have clean test resources and dependencies. Tests are no 2nd class artifacts compared to production code! For what it is worth, I have shared three sample projects (BoM, resources/dependencies artifact and a project using them) on GitHub and added links to my answer. Enjoy - or ignore.

Comment: You are not ready to change your test code in order to make it work?!? If you are unwilling to fix it, why are you asking a question here?

Comment: When I said changing code I didn't make it explicity clear to you... I'm obviously willing to change test code, but the code snippit I posted was "real code" inside the method that's been called in my spock test. 

I will certainly take a look at your examples thanks... I obviously can't do something too crazy though I'm in a corp env.

Comment: Oh, it is a production resource, not a test resource. Well, then it is simple: `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource.txt")` will work both locally and in JARs, also both in production and test code. For me it does, anyway. You need to go via a production class's classloader from the same artifact - really simple.